# How to pass image from a flex application to a asp net c# web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache-flex, web-services, flex4

I want to store images from the flex application to a asp net web service and at a later point will be sending these images back to flex application . Can you please give a example web method in c# or suggest a website to read about how to do this. I tried goggling but couldn't find anything very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

- use AMF and send ByteArray to C# [(flex to c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103061/best-way-for-flex-to-communicate-with-c-backend)
- use URLRequest and it's data property to send ByteArray encoded in Base64 via HTTP POST