# How to pass the byte array from flex to dotnet

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

In my project we need to save the image taken from webcam in a default path using flex 4.6 but giving a default path in flex(saving the image in a default path like C:\temp..) is not possible so we are passing the byte array of that captured image from flex to .ashx page in .net here,image is saving in a default path but imagebytes is not saving(showing that no data in image).If any body knows please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the succeeded in passing the imagebytes from flex to ashx page like below

```
//Declare a string in script tag(Initialize a string before init() )
[Bindable]public var str64enc:String="";

//creating object for bytearray
[Bindable]public var imgbytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray(); 

//creating object for bitmapdata
[Bindable]public var picture1:BitmapData=new BitmapData(103,103,true);

**In your code**
var png:PNGEncoder=new PNGEncoder();
imgbytes=png.encode(picture1);

var base64enc:Base64Encoder=new Base64Encoder();
base64enc.encodeBytes(imgbytes);

str64enc=base64enc.toString();
```

STEP-BY-STEP PROCEDURE:-------

1-Take a base64encoder and encode the bytearray as below:

```
var base64enc:Base64Encoder=new Base64Encoder();
base64enc.encodeBytes(imgbytes);
```

2-then assign that base64 encoder object(In this case" base64enc") to string

3-In HTTPSERVICE u need to pass that string like:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="savepcktdata" method="POST"
    url="ur's destination path like..(axis/security/security.aspx)"
        result="savepcktdata_resultHandler(event)"                      
        resultFormat="text">
            <mx:request>
    <Operation>savepcktdata</Operation>     

    <bytes>
           {str64enc}
    </bytes>

    </mx:request>   
</mx:HTTPService>
```

4- In .aspx page u need to retrieve like:

```
string str = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["bytes"]);
```

cocnclusion:In order to pass the image bytes from flex(flash builder 4.6) to dotnet
    (visual    studio) you need to pass through the base64 string like above code.

Below is the useful link related to this issue

[How to pass image from a flex application to a asp net c# web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702239/how-to-pass-image-from-a-flex-application-to-a-) asp-net-c-sharp-web-service